# How can I stop zombie processes from being left behind by Puppeteer without --no-sandbox?

Tags: puppeteer

I don't want to use `--no-sandbox` for security reasons, but without it, I can't use `--no-zygote` which is the only solution I could find to prevent zombie process from being created. How can I achieve the same goal of cleaning up zombie processes without `--no-sandbox`? I know about dumb-init, but I want to know if there is a way to keep the processet from becoming zombies in the first place.

The zombie processes left behind are like this

```
$ ps aux | grep chrome | head -n 10
app         60  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    Mar24   0:00 [chrome_crashpad] <defunct>
app         65  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    Mar24   0:00 [chrome] <defunct>
app         66  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    Mar24   0:00 [chrome] <defunct>
app         82  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    Mar24   0:00 [chrome] <defunct>
app        163  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    Mar24   0:00 [chrome] <defunct>
app        179  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    Mar24   0:00 [chrome_crashpad] <defunct>
app        184  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    Mar24   0:00 [chrome] <defunct>
app        185  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    Mar24   0:00 [chrome] <defunct>
app        202  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    Mar24   0:00 [chrome] <defunct>
app        285  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    Mar24   0:00 [chrome] <defunct>
```

Comment: What zombie processes are being left behind? You are calling `.finally(() => browser?.close())` I assume?

Comment: I'll update my question with `ps aux` output, and yes I am calling `browser.close()`.

Comment: Thanks -- please provide a [mcve] of the code that produces this.

Comment: Zombie processes are a known issue already, hence the recommendation of using dumb-init in the Puppeteer documentation. My question is if there is a way to reap the zombies without dumb-init.

Comment: A reference to `dumb-init` in the docs would be nice. I haven't had this problem as far as I know and I'm not familiar with the issue, which is why I'm curious about the code details. I suspect proper cleanup of the resources would solve the problem, and if not, then I'd like to know what sort of code is creating the root cause, and if no code pattern is causing the problem, what can I run to see the issue? Just any old Puppeteer app will leave behind zombie processes I can see?

Comment: It seems like this is a problem specific to Docker, or in any case when Puppeteer is run on PID 1, because PID 1 is a special case which causes process to become defunct even if we call `browser.close()` like we're supposed to. This GitHub issue is pretty much the same issue I had, which I ended up solving with dumb-init https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1825

The reference to dumb-init is in the troubleshooting documentation https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md

Comment: Great, all of that helps. I'd add it as an [edit] to the question for posterity.

Comment: @RickyKazuoMiller have you been able to solve the issue? am I right your biggest pain point is that you can only kill the zombie processes if you have `--no-zygote` and `--no-sandbox` launch flags, but you want to avoid running chrome without sandbox? setting up your own Linux sandboxing isn't an option? I suppose like that `--no-zygote` would be enough and you wouldn't have security concerns.